# Attaching entity repository to mail

Tags: nestjs

I'm quite new to coding so apologies if there's a simple solution i'm glossing over but I've been trying for a while an do haven't been able to get it

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MailerService } from '@nestjs-modules/mailer';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { ChecklistItemsEntity } from 'src/checklist-items/checklist-items.entity';



const mail = 'welcome'
@Injectable()
export class MailService {
  constructor( public mailerService: MailerService) {}

  public example(): void {
    this
      .mailerService
      .sendMail({
        to: 'ashwin.iyer01@gmail.com', // List of receivers email address
        from: 'ashwin.iyer01@gmail.com', // Senders email address
        subject: 'Testing Nest MailerModule ✔', // Subject line
        text: 'welcome', // plaintext body
        html: mail , // HTML body content
      })
      .then((success) => {
        console.log(success)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      });
  }
```

This is a part of the application i'm building, its doing its job as intended and sending sample emails however i need the emails to include data from the MySQL database that the application is linked to instead of 'welcome'.

Specifically i need it to contain all the records of one table in the database, an entity(i'm using TypeORM).

How would i go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just have a typeorm repository added to the service, make the query to the data, serialize the data back into an HTML compliant format, and then add it to the `html` or `text` property. Or even better, you could inject the `MailService` into something like the `UsertService` that has a `UserRepo` already in it, and create a function that takes the already serialized information, then from the `UserService` call `this.mailService.sendMail(data)` and let everything happen from there.